# How to manage full-screen dialogs in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm thinking about dialogs appearance. Quoting the [design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-full-screen-dialogs):

> Because of limited real estate on mobile devices, content that may
>   appear as a dialog in other form factors (tablet, desktop, etc.) may
>   be more appropriately presented in a full-screen dialog.

And that seems reasonable to me. Stuff about presenting a Dialog as embedded / full-screen depending on screen size are also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog). Basically, you can:

- for small screens, override `public Dialog onCreateDialog()` in your `DialogFragment` and call `.show()`;
- for wide screens, override also `public View onCreateView()` and commit a fragment transaction.

I approached this as an easy task, but I have some concept issues about the full-screen dialogs and how to manage them. I'm not even sure the [**design guidelines full-screen dialog**](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7bkw4S1dWazgzdms/components_dialogs_fullscreen1.png) is really a `DialogFragment`.

E.g., in the pic I linked the full-screen fragment dialog has a Toolbar.

> In full-screen dialogs, the confirmation and dismissive actions are at
>   the top of the screen.

Toolbar style for full-screen dialogs is pretty peculiar: X to dismiss, title, confirm action on the right. These items are the full-screen version of items in a floating `AlertDialog`, nothing new here.

What I'm wondering is - do I have to deal with these actions twice, once for the floating and once for the full-screen version? Do I have to style both versions of the dialog?

Moreover, where does that Toolbar come from? Should we load the dialog fragment into `android.R.id.content` and add a `Toolbar` inside the fragment? Should we load it into the actual activity layout, and redesign the toolbar at runtime? Should we treat the dialog fragment as a `Dialog`, and `show()` it with particular window attributes (but then, removing buttons at the bottom, and adding a toolbar..)?

I was thinking that this process was automatically managed by the `DialogFragment` class, but it doesn't looks so.

Comment: Same doubts here on how to implement this smoothly. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Luccas never tried. I believe you could implement a standard dialog onCreateDialog() with your view, and onCreateView() you return the same layout but with a toolbar at the top. That's the easier way as I see it now. Also for a better look you should use AppCompatDialogFragment rather than DialogFragment.